# List<string> appending char from both sides of each value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I get the name of all the columns that were returned in my SqlDataReader with LINQ(I have added the code). I want to add in this line of LINQ a code that appending "{"  "}" for each string in the collection. For example if the value is "Hello" I want it to be "{Hello}".

```
var columns = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();
```

Comment: [...].Select("{" + reader.GetName + "}").ToList();

Answer (score 4):

A few different ways

**Given**

[`SqlDataReader.GetName(Int32) Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

> Gets the name of the specified column.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> The zero-based column ordinal.

**Examples**

```
var columns = Enumerable
    .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
    .Select(i => $"{{{reader.GetName(i)}}}")
    .ToList();

// or

var columns = Enumerable
    .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
    .Select(i => "{" + reader.GetName(i) + "}")
    .ToList();

// or

var columns = Enumerable
    .Range(0, reader.FieldCount)
    .Select(reader.GetName)
    .Select(x=> $"{{{x}}}")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: *I am only answering this because everyone else got it wrong*   Thanks for stepping in

Answer (score 1):

You can do it

```
sourceCollection.Select(str => $"{{{str}}}").ToList();
```